# Three js obj loader big file

Tags: three.js

I have a file OBJ with lots of features and vertices, more than 800 000. When I load it through OBZhMTLoader does just hangs, freez. Warning that the script crashes freezes. Help pleas.

```
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                            //console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                        }
                    };

                    var onError = function ( xhr ) {
                    };

                    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                    loader.load( '13/13.obj', '13/13.mtl', function ( object ) {
scene.add( object )
}, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: I think you should try to isolate the problem. Do you have the same issue by loading the obj only, with `OBJLoader` ?

Comment: How to isolate the problem? And how else can you upload the object, I just try and through OBJ

Comment: I thought you could load the .obj _only_, with `THREE.OBJLoader` - without the .mtl part - so you'll see if the problem really comes from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use OBJLoader instead of OBJMTLLoader.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5250